# How to execute command in `ms-sql-server` container?

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am now trying to simulate the production environment.
**Ultimate Goals:**
1. `Apache`
2. `php5`
3. `Microsoft SQL Server`
4. `Create database`
5. `Make database schema`
6. `Connect from website`

3 of them I can simply achieves by `DockerFile` and `docker-compose.yml`
Problem is 4th

`DockerFile`

```
FROM debian:7

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php5-sybase apache2


RUN mkdir /source
WORKDIR /source

COPY application ./applications
COPY assets ./assets
COPY pushnotification ./pushnotification
COPY system ./system
COPY uploads ./uploads
COPY web.config .
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:

  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: <password>
      MSSQL_PID: Developer
    restart: "always"
    ports:
        - "1433:1433"

  backend:
    container_name: gen365-cms
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    links:
      - mssql
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
```

I am trying to create database according to [manual](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)

```
$ docker exec -it a3063bbff978 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P phohHa0gyahh2Vah
1> select Name from sys.databases;
2> \q
3> ;
4> exit
```

**Question:**
How can I create database to my `container`?

Comment: Have you looked through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker, especialy the bit  on 'Create and query data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Dockerfile for SQL Server and use COPY command  to copy sql script file( with commands to create Databases and schema )and use RUN command to run the sql script while creating image and create the container from the Image. It will solve the problem.

Refer to the link below:
https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the SQL container, and then use SSMS and run whatever scripts are needed to create the database?   Then, stop the container, and commit it to an image, and you'll be good to go with an image supporting delivery of n instances?